# Can method return more than one type

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to understand the below code:

```
int someMethod() {
    return (true ? null : 0);
}
```

The method's return type is `int`, but it can return both `null` and `int`, is this correct behavior in Java? Can a Java method return more than one type? This may sound silly for those who are experienced, but I have just took my first step in Java.

Comment: yes, it compiled without error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method cannot return more than one type.

The signature of a method contains the return type or `void` if the method doesn't return anything. Since it must be defined in the method signature, you **must** return something of that type.

The code

```
return (true ? null : 0);
```

is a shorthand if-else statement, or conditional ternary expression, and can be rewritten to this:

```
if (true) {
    return null;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

<strike>The above code, however, won't compile since one cannot return `null` if the return type is the [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `int`</strike>. The above code will compile, because the JVM will try to convert null to an `int`, due to auto-unboxing. At runtime, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, as [pointed out by Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903062/can-method-return-more-than-one-type/31903081#31903081).

In order to 'return multiple types', you could do the following:

```
public class BooleanOrInt {

    private boolean isInteger; // Whether value is boolean or int
    private boolean b;
    private int i;

    public BooleanOrInt(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
        this.isInteger = false;
    }

    public BooleanOrInt(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        this.isInteger = true;
    }

    public boolean isInteger() {
        return this.isInteger;
    }
}
```

And then your code should be as follows:

```
BooleanOrInt methodOfA() {
    if (someCondition) {
        return new BooleanOrInt(theBooleanYouWant);
    }
    else {
        return new BooleanOrInt(theIntegerYouWant);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to return boolean and int from same method?

Comment: @AyushiShah - If that is the case, then you should wrap them in a Class and return that Class' object from the method! Your method return type would then change to the Class type in that case.

Comment: @AyushiShah You can't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @AyushiShah However, I edited my answer to your question to point out a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

It's a conditional ternary expression, which means the method returns one of the two values following the `?`, depending on the evaluation of the condition he appears prior to `?` (which in your case always returns `true`).

The type of the expression `(true ? null : 0)` is `Integer`, since that's the common type for `null` and `0`.

Your code will throw a `NullPointerException`, since when you return a `null` `Integer` in a method whose return type is `int`, the JVM attempts to convert the `Integer` to `int` and fails.

In order to fix this code, you'll have to change the return type to `Integer` (which is the reference type that serves as a wrapper for the `int` primitive type) :

```
Integer methodOfA()
{
    return (true ? null : 0);
}
```

Comment: it does not give me compilation error even if I keep int as return type

Comment: @AyushiShah Yes, I just fixed the answer.

Comment: I believe int and Integer are both same, correct me if am wrong?

Comment: @AyushiShah They are not. `Integer` is a class that contains an `int` value.

Comment: [It does actually seem to compile](https://ideone.com/KovSi2), but causes a runtime error.

Comment: @Siguza yes i also thought it should be a compiler error but no .if we use if else instead of ternary then it's a compile error .it's a good question

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Java method cannot return more than one type in the form you are suggesting. However, it can return any number of sub-types. In your case, int is a primitive type and it cannot have sub-types. Here you cannot return null since null can only be returned by methods whose return type is an object. For primitives you have to specify some values (0 in your case).